# Machu Pichhu/Cusco four days DIY hiking trips suggestions

Tags: machu-picchu

We are planning on a trip to Cusco area for four/five days in December.  We are buying necessary tickets to go to Machu Pichhu and Montana. Tickets to the other trails via http://www.machupicchu.gob.pe/ are sold out. Would you suggest DIY day hikes or treks around Ollantaytambo, Aguas Calientes, or Cusco for the other 3 days? Any links or book suggestions will be nice.

Comment: Are you asking about a trek/hike from Cusco to Aguas Calientes? That would be murderous.  I wouldn't try it without a large group, but then it's been several years since I wandered about in that region.

Comment: I am interested in day hikes of 6 to 8 miles using Cusco/Ollantayatambo/Arias Calientes as a starting point. We would like these hikes to be separate from our alteady committed trip to Machu Pichhu + Montana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ollantaytambo is better suited for hikes than Cusco. But, you can easily go for hikes around Cusco as well.
The possibilities from Aguas Callientes are limited. (And, it's not a very nice town if you're not going to Machu Picchu.)

In Cusco, everyone and their brother will be able and willing to get you on day tours. But, I would probably start by asking the guys from the [Cusco Free Walking Tour](http://www.fwtperu.com). I'm not affiliated, but, their city tour is quite good (though their tour in Arequipa is, well, awesome) and I'd say they genuinely will try to help you in finding good day trips, or point you to the people that can.